# Latest kernel sources not available for installation? (Fedora 26 Beta)

Tags: fedora, kernel, source-code

I just stumbled across a problem where the installed kernel sources don't match the kernel that I'm actually running.

I'm running `4.11.7-300.fc26.x86_64`:

```
[root@localhost VirtualBoxGuestAdditions]# uname -r
4.11.7-300.fc26.x86_64
```

But the latest kernel sources don't seem to have the same version:

```
[root@localhost VirtualBoxGuestAdditions]# yum install kernel-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:30:50 ago on Wed 28 Jun 2017 04:11:01 PM CEST.
Package kernel-devel-4.11.6-301.fc26.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

And looking at `/usr/src/kernels/` surely enough, I only have the old sources:

```
[root@localhost VirtualBoxGuestAdditions]# ls -la /usr/src/kernels/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jun 28 16:22 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Jun 28 16:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root 4096 Jun 28 16:22 4.11.6-301.fc26.x86_64
```

So I tried to specify the version manually, but without success:

```
[root@localhost VirtualBoxGuestAdditions]# yum install kernel-devel-4.11.7-300.fc26
Last metadata expiration check: 1:27:40 ago on Wed 28 Jun 2017 04:11:01 PM CEST.
No package kernel-devel-4.11.7-300.fc26 available.
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Is this normal? What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that this is merely a transient mirroring problem. Try

```
sudo dnf --refresh upgrade kernel-devel
```

(Or possibly just a general `sudo dnf --refresh upgrade`.)